# How to make images appear in the view with its labels in UICollectionView cells using Alamofire?

Tags: ios, swift3, uicollectionview, alamofireimage

I'm making an app like the AppStore with UICollectionView so when downloading the data from url

```
import Alamofire
import AlamofireImage

class AppCategory: NSObject {
var id: NSNumber?
var title: String?
var apps: [App]?
var type: NSNumber?

static func fetchFeaturedApps(completionHandler: @escaping ([AppCategory]) -> ()) {

let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as! [String: AnyObject]
var appCategories = [AppCategory]()
             let sections = OFFERIM["sections"] as! [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>]
            for i in 0..<sections.count {
                var appCategory = AppCategory()
                var apps = [App]()

                let sectionTitle = sections[i]["title"] as! String
                appCategory.title = sectionTitle
                let sectionType = sections[i]["type"] as! NSNumber
                appCategory.type = sectionType
                let sectionId = sections[i]["id"] as! NSNumber
                appCategory.id = sectionId
                // for Apps inside each section
                let lists = sections[i]["lists"] as! [String: AnyObject]
                 for j in 0..<lists.count{
                    let app = App()

                    let id = lists[j]["id"] as! NSNumber
                    app.id = id

                    let thumb = lists[j]["thumb"]! as! String

                    Alamofire.request(thumb).responseImage { response in

                        if let image = response.result.value {
                            app.image = image
                            print("image downloaded: \(image)")
                        }
                    }
                    let title = lists[j]["title"] as! String
                    app.title = title

                    apps.append(app)
                }
                appCategory.apps = apps
                appCategories.append(appCategory)
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                completionHandler(appCategories)
            })
        }catch{
            print("JSON Processing Failed")
        }
        }.resume()
}
}
```

and I have these classes as models

```
class App: NSObject {
var id: NSNumber?
var title: String?
var image: UIImage?

}
```

and I call `featuredApps` in the `viewDidLoad` in viewController 
what happened is when the view loaded the labels appears but the images not in the collection view .

I need to  scroll each row to make the images appear.

and I don't kwon the problem where ???

Comment: are you calling collectionView.reloadData()? If you see them after you scroll this may be the issue.

Comment: @JustinM Absolutely I called after the calling of this static func

Comment: the alamofire request for images is in its own closure so most likely your calling your completionHandler before the images are downloaded. Since you see the images when you scroll it has to do with the timing of getting the images and reloading the collection view

Comment: @JustinM So what's your suggestion ?

Comment: as a beginning step figure out the total number of images you expect to be downloading and on that count call your completion handler from inside the download image function. If you can download the images ahead of time on a background thread you can cache them and make it more responsive. It's something you might have to mess with to get an idea of what works best.

Comment: I'll try it, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep the url and set the url to image view use AlamofireImage.

```
imageView.af_setImage(withURL: url)
```

Comment: The same result  !